# angular clear form

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Totally new to angular and appreciate any help received. I'm trying to build a satisfaction app in angular, I am using ng-show to pose the questions one at a time and collecting the data and sending it to firebase at the end. The difficulty I am having is clearing the answers previously give. I have tried resetting the scope and using $setPristine() but keep getting an error.

HTML

```
<div id = "question" class="row" ng-show="question">
    <div id="badResponse"  ng-click="selectResponse('bad')">
    </div>
    <div id="goodResponse" ng-click="selectResponse('good')">
    </div>
</div>

<div ng-show="why">
<ul ng-repeat="option in whyOptions">
  <li><input type="checkbox" class="reason" checklist-model="form.why" checklist-value="option">{{option}}</li>
</ul>
 <button id ="enterBtn" ng-click="responseReason()">Next</button>
</div>

<div ng-show="more" class="more">
  <button id ="skipBtn" ng-click="moreInfo()">{{form.extraInfo.length != 0 ? 'Next' : 'Skip'}}</button>
</div>

<div ng-show="thankYou">
  <button id ="thankYouBtn" ng-click="thankYouFunction()">Home</button>
</div>
```

JS

```
$scope.form = {
  experience: '',
  extraInfo: ''
};

$scope.whyOptions = [
  'reason 1',
  'reason 2',
];

$scope.selectResponse = function(response) {
  $scope.form.experience = response;
};


$scope.thankYouFunction = function() {
  $scope.responses.$add({
    customerRsponse: $scope.form
  });
  $scope.form.$setPristine();
};

});
```

Comment: Too much code. If you need to understand the basic concepts, reduce your example to deal *only* with that concept. No need for extra markup or irrelevant parts (like `moreInfo`).

Comment: Removed the extra code to just the form components. Hope that is better

Comment: So $scope.form = {
  experience: '',
  extraInfo: ''
}; doesn't work in the thankYouFunction?

Comment: Yes, much better... So, where are the form values stored? Or in other words, is `$scope.form` the object to which form's input controls bound to? If so, then just reset it - `$scope.form = {}`

Comment: I tried $scope.form = { experience: '', extraInfo: '' };

$scope.form is the object that the input controls are bound to yes. Should I also add   $scope.form.why= {}; as I'm using checklist-model as it was recommend to me for the checkboxes

Comment: All working now. Just wanted to say thank you for helping :-)